# Limit hosts using Workflow Template

Tags: ansible-tower, ansible-awx

I'm using Ansible AWX (Tower) and have a template workflow that executes several templates one after the other, based on if the previous execution was successful.

I noticed I can limit to a specific host when running a single template, I'd like to apply this to the a workflow and my guess is I would have to use the survey option to achieve this, however I'm not sure how.

I have tried to see if I can override the "hosts" value and that failed like I expected it to.
How can I go about having it ask me at the beginning of the workflow for the hostname/ip and not for every single template inside the workflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the `set_stats` option.

Let's suppose you have the following inventory:

- 10.100.1.1
- 10.100.1.3
- 10.100.1.6

Your inventory is called **MyOfficeInventory**. First rule is that you need this inventory across all your Templates to play with the host from the first one.

I want to ping only my *10.100.1.6* machine, so in the Template I choose **MyOfficeInventory** and limit to *10.100.1.6*.

If we do:

```
---
- name: Ping
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  connection: local

  tasks:

  - name: Ping
    ping:
```

We get:

```
TASK [Ping] ********************************************************************
ok: [10.100.10.6]
```

Cool! So from **MyOfficeInventory** I have my only host selected pinged. So now, in my workflow I have the next Template with *MyOfficeInventory** selected (This is the rule as said). If I ping, I will ping all of them unless you limit again so let's do the magic:

In your first Template do:

```
  - name:  add devices with connectivity to the "working_hosts" group
    group_by:
      key: working_hosts

  - name: "Artifact URL of test results to Tower Workflows"
    set_stats:
      data:
        myinventory:  "{{ groups['working_hosts'] }}"
    run_once: True
```

Be careful, because for your playbook,

```
groups['all']
```

means:

```
"groups['all']": [
    "10.100.10.1",
    "10.100.10.3", 
    "10.100.10.6"
]
```

And with your new working_hosts group, you get only your current host:

```
"groups['working_hosts']": [
    "10.100.10.6"
]
```

So now you have your brand new **myinventory** inventory.

Use it like this in the rest of your Playbooks assigned to your Templates:

---

```
- name: Ping
  hosts: "{{ myinventory }}"
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:

  - name: Ping
    ping:
```

Your inventory variable will be transferred and you will get:

```
ok: [10.100.10.6]
```

One step further. Do you want to select your host from a Survey?

Create one with your hostname input and add keep your first Playbook as:

```
- name: Ping
  hosts: "{{ mysurveyhost }}"
  gather_facts: False
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware I could use a variable to define hosts. I usually run a syntax check before doing a live run and it complained about it being an invalid value, but it does in fact run without errors when defining that variable in a survey.

Comment: Yes, indeed, but remember using the same inventory across your Templates and only changing it adding all the hosts you are going to work with. You are welcomed!!!